# When applying the Having clause in Impala, a reference error occurs

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, impala, having

Error occurs when referencing expr_1 after running the query like this on Impala.:

```
import pyodbc

import pandas as pd

sql = """
SELECT
    col,
    SUM(col2)
FROM table
WHERE conds
GROUP BY col
HAVING SUM(col2) > 0
"""

with pyodbc.connect(dsn=DSN, driver=CONN_DRIVER, schema=schema, autocommit=True) as conn:

    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

It seems that an error has occurred after the GROUP BY is applied.
How can it be solved?

Removing the aggregation function from the SELECT statement or eliminating the Having clause should solve the problem.
However, HUE displays the result without any issues, so it seems to be a pyodbc issue.

Comment: this seems to be a correct SQL statement in Impala. its possible pyodbc isnt passing correct arguments/statement to impala. can you pls share more like actual py code?

Comment: @KoushikRoy Thank you for the comment. However, there is nothing special in the query listed above except the table and column name.

Comment: @KoushikRoy I did add some python code above.

Comment: Dont you have to define `sql` like `sql='SELECT     col,     SUM(col2) FROM table WHERE conds GROUP BY col HAVING SUM(col2) > 0'` before using it?

Comment: @KoushikRoy I have assigned the variable, of course. I have edited the above again.

Comment: can you pls make `sql=` a single line like i mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Sadly, the result remains the same even if the query is changed to one line.

Comment: can you pls try - `read_sql_query()`?

Comment: @KoushikRoy Unfortunately, the result is the same for read_sql_query.